# Clear values from people editor SharePoint control

Tags: c#, sharepoint, peoplepicker

I have a PeopleEditor control on my page. User can add users to people picker and I have a button that sends some sort of email to to those users. However, the values in the People picker value remains even after the postback.

Does anyone knows how to clear the fields programmatically?

I have tried this but didn't do anything: http://jyothsnag.blogspot.com/2011/04/clearing-people-picker-control.html

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you debug from the browser, do you get any errors?

Comment: I am not getting any errors, I am just trying to clear the users in  PeopleEditor field.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?
PeopleEditor.CommaSeparatedAccounts = null

Answer (score 0):

> you can give a try to `PeopleEditor.ResolvedEntities.Clear();` 
>   works on fly.